# SecurityException in getPassword of accountManager in android

Tags: android, google-account, accountmanager, getpasswd

I'm trying to  retrieve the password of google account, but getting
security exception at String pwd = AccountManager.get(mContext).getPassword(account).
Also i have given permissions in androidManifest.xml to
account_manager, aunthenticator, get_account, manage account.

## code :

```
android.accounts.Account[] gaccounts = AccountManager.get(mContext).getAccounts();
Log.i("parul", "2222()len :"+ gaccounts.length);
for (android.accounts.Account account: gaccounts) {
   String pwd = AccountManager.get(mContext).getPassword(account);
   Log.i("parul", "google pwd: " + pwd);
   AccountManager.get(mContext).setPassword(account, null);
   String pwdcleared = AccountManager.get(mContext).getPassword(account);
   Log.i("parul", "google pwdcleared: " + pwdcleared);
}
```

=============================================================================

## Exception:

08-04 06:38:30.821: WARN/AccountManagerService(2248): caller uid 1000
is different than the authenticator's uid

08-04 06:38:30.821: INFO/parul(2804): exception thrown for account
manager try block

08-04 06:38:30.821: WARN/System.err(2804): java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 1000 is different than the
authenticator's uid

08-04 06:38:30.821: WARN/System.err(2804):     at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1218)

08-04 06:38:30.821: WARN/System.err(2804):     at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1206)

08-04 06:38:30.821: WARN/System.err(2804):     at
android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub
$Proxy.getPassword(IAccountManager.java:397)

08-04 06:38:30.821: WARN/System.err(2804):     at
android.accounts.AccountManager.getPassword(AccountManager.java:157)

=============================================================================

If anybody is aware why i'm getting this problem plz help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I [**read this post**](http://loganandandy.tumblr.com/post/613041897/caller-uid-is-different), the error is because of mismatch configuration. You need to dedug in details

Answer (score 0):

I don't think (it is only a guess) you can retrieve Google account password. 
BTW, if you need Google account password to validate user at your service, I suggest another way to do this. Get user's token and pass it to server over **secured** channel.

See details in my answer here:
[User authentication at your service by using AccountManager token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352592/webservice-credentials-openid-android-accountmanager/6680837#6680837)