# Error on getting UserName and Password

Tags: android, gmail, accountmanager

When trying to get Gmail username and password from account manager, the following exception occurs:

`java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10073` is different than the authenticator's uid

```
 AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(mContex);
 Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(mContex).getAccounts();
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                String possibleEmail = account.name;                    
                String possiblePassword = accountManager.getPassword(account) ;                 
                System.out.println("User name :- "+possibleEmail);
                System.out.println("User Password :- "+possiblePassword);

            }

        }
```

added permission in Manifest.xml :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"></uses-permission> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this exception?

Comment: Post your account-authenticator of xml and your class AuthenticatorService.

Comment: someone already posted something similar  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403885/securityexception-in-getpassword-of-accountmanager-in-android

Comment: it's nt possible to get password. username we will get

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Only the authenticator that manages an account can access the stored credentials (the Google authenticator, in this case).

See [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) for information on how to request a secure token from the authenticator using `getAuthToken()`, which will allow you to login to the account (but will not provide you with the user's password).

> Many servers support some notion of an authentication token, which can
>   be used to authenticate a request to the server without sending the
>   user's actual password. (Auth tokens are normally created with a
>   separate request which does include the user's credentials.)
>   AccountManager can generate auth tokens for applications, so the
>   application doesn't need to handle passwords directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded that from github then make sure that String ACCOUNT_TYPE in class is same as constant in the XML definition for Your authenticator.

In file1.java

```
class AuthenticatorService extends Service {
public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.joelapenna.foursquared";
```

In file1.xml

```
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="com.joelapenna.foursquared.account" ... />
```

Remove " ... " in xml file , this Cause the string mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext())
                .getAccounts();

        for (Account account : accounts) {

            if (account.name.endsWith("gmail.com")) {

            String  email = account.name;


            }

        }
```

Comment: Problem is getting Password not User name.