# Android AccountManager and Google OpenID

Tags: android, openid, accountmanager

I know this seems like a duplicate question but I've read many of the others including [Webservice credentials - OpenID/Android AccountManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352592/webservice-credentials-openid-android-accountmanager). Here's my situation:

I'm currently working on a project mainly for educational purposes and personal use. Its a Web application written in PHP that allows you to remotely manage your phone (silence, set an alarm, locate, ect.) What I would like to do is allow users to have accounts where their phone(s) is/are listed and managed without having to develop an entire Auth/User Managment system. I thought it would be easy to implement with AccountManager but I'm getting strange error like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock
```

In anger and frustration, I've since deleted that code and so can't post what caused it. Without being able to tie phones to accounts, I have no way of managing the device remotely. One of the parts I'm confused with is how to use the authToken. I don't need to use any google services, I just want to know if it's a valid google account then store their Google email in a database on the server side.

If anyone could give me some example code or maybe a tutorial, that would be amazing. Also, if anyone thinks that I'm going about this the wrong way, please let me know.

P.S. I'm good at being vague and forgetting details so I apologize for any misunderstandings beforehand.