# Android Simple client app sending text to google cloud datastore ? example, hints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gwt, android-widget

I am new to this environment and trying to explore while doing this task.

Description: The client application should display a textbox of any kind, and a submit button of any kind.

Assumptions: The server should be written in Google Application Framework and deployed online in a Google Application Framework account.

Comment: What's the relationship with GWT? (you used it as a tag), and what is "Google Application Framework" ?

Comment: Good question - what is "Google Application Framework"? I've never heard of it before, and I work here.

Answer (score 1):

All in all, this is not an easy task.

First read tutorials on all your basic technologies: AppEngine and Android. There are plenty around. You should know how to make a text box on Android and handle click events.

Then to post some data to AppEngine from Android you'll need:

1. The hardest part - user authentication. Three options:

   - Your own username/passwords. You need a signup/login pages on AppEngine and at least a login page on Android. You also need a email confirmation.
   - OpenID. [Easy to setup](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html) on AppEngine. Hard to do on Android: [Webservice credentials - OpenID/Android AccountManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352592/webservice-credentials-openid-android-accountmanager/5030084#5030084)
   - OAuth. [Easy](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/04/12/oauth-android-google-apis-client-library-java/) on Appengine. [Pretty easy](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/04/12/oauth-android-google-apis-client-library-java/) on Android. Requires Google account on Android phone and access to it (app privileges - not all people like this).
2. REST service on AppEngine. Use [Resteasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/docs). And [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) for JSON conversion.
3. REST client on Android. [Example](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/), [video](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html). Also use [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

Comment: Thank you Peter , Nice Fragmentation of solution and help.