# Android: access google accounts information

Tags: android, account, accountmanager

I working for an app that requires google login. I need to access provider_uid, email, display name, first name, last name.

I managed to iterate all google accounts from the device and present them in a list. After the user perform a click on a list item, I access the selected account auth_token via AccountManagerCallback. But I need provier_uid(an example: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=Alt....) and the fields enumerated above. I suppose I must perform some request to google server where to query this information (and passing account token key to request), but I didn't find any docs for this(only authentication, authorization - using ClientLogin, OAuth 2.0 and OpenId).

It's my first time when handling google auth(except picassa and yoututbe auth+upload).

I need this to update a database and be able to authenticate the user(which has the option to upload images and do other things on my server).

Thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem ( [Webservice credentials - OpenID/Android AccountManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352592/webservice-credentials-openid-android-accountmanager/6680837#6680837) - see Igor Zubchenok answer).

Now I send the auth token to my server where I use gdata/gauva jars to getter informations about the account.