# Make browser cookies available in a webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, session-cookies

Is it possible to make the cookies of the default browser available in a webview? I want to use a webview for authentification and since the webview uses its own cookie store by default, my users would have to enter their credetials a second time, and that is something I really would like to avoid.

[edit] what I forgot to add: I am using google and facebook as openid-providers for the login, and and it is more than likely users are already loggeg in with this account. So in a web-browser they would not be required to enter their credentials, but in a webview they are. And I really think it is bad practice to ask for a google or facebook password in a webview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to make the cookies of the default browser available in a webview?

No, sorry.

> I want to use a webview for authentification and since the webview uses its own cookie store by default, my users would have to enter their credetials a second time, and that is something I really would like to avoid.

Then either:

- use the `WebView` for the entire experience, or
- use the user's choice of browser for the entire experience, or
- use something other than cookies for session tracking (e.g., `jsession` values in the URL)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was just considering to use an webview for the authentification since I was not able to obtain a suitable token for a custom backend from the account manager: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565759/obtaining-a-basic-google-auth-token-from-accountmanager. I do already have a native app but want to migrate the backend from Appengine to Heroku. Until now I requested a token of the type "ah" (AppEngine) from the AccountManager.