# Use SyncAdapter to sync with *local* gmail and facebook app data

Tags: android, facebook, gmail, android-syncadapter

For an app I need to develop, I need to be able to sync with both gmail and facebook data  using a SyncAdapter.  I'm hoping to sync with the local facebook and gmail apps (if available) instead their remote servers.  Syncing with the local apps would mean less battery usage, less network usage, faster syncing, etc.  Of course, if needed, I will set the correct permissions.

**My questions**:

- If any of the apps (gmail/facebook) are available, is it possible to query them for data (messages, events, etc.)?
- If not, is it possible to get an authentication token (or any kind of credential) from them that will allow me to query the server without the user needing to put in a username and password of each of them again?
- If that's possible, is it also possible to automatically sync immediately after either of the facebook or gmail apps sync, so that I get new data as soon as they do?

If none of these are available, I guess I'll need to fetch the data myself, so that's not relevant for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak for Facebook, but the GMail app doesn't allow this. It used to work previously, but they have since secured it so that only Google apps can query the email content provider. The best you can do is get the number of messages with the [labels API](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html). You can get an authentication token (ClientLogin or OAuth2) for Google services using the standard Android `AccountManager`. You will then have to use it to connect to the particular API to get the actual data.

Comment: what are the possible things i can do with this OAuth2 token? also , how come google has so many services that i can use , but gmail is not a part of them?

Comment: GMail has at least an RSS interface that you can get using the OAuth token. There might other APIs too, you should research about it. Chances are you can authenticate to pretty much anything Google offers using the token.

Comment: but can i read all messages , including those that were read ?

Comment: I don't know the details off the top of my head, use Google, the search engine :)

Comment: i have , believe me i have .... that's why i hoped to find anyone who had experience with this problem here.

Comment: i also wonder how the app "friday" works . i haven't tested it , but it's supposed to track all of the activities (FB,gmail,...) you are having

Comment: Well, the standard ways to interact with Gmail are SMTP and IMAP. The SMTP authentication routine is modified to accept a token, so you can send email without needing the actual password. I'm pretty sure IMAP works in a similar way. So, you basically have to write an SMTP and IMAP clients (if you *really* search you can find ready-made once that work with GMail), integrate them in your app and create some sort of interface.

Comment: could you please provide a link of something that you know that works?

Comment: Documentation is here, try it out: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_protocol#imap

Comment: hmmm... seems promising . so you say i don't have to use userName and/or password in order to fetch email , and i can use it , along with an email library (like this one: http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/ ) ?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, now I've better understood your question.  I don't think that there's any way to get the data you're interested in directly from the local copies of the apps.  It's an interesting idea, and reasonable for the speed/space/bandwidth reasons you suggest, but would require significant support from the apps that's not currently available.

Trying to avoid the user re-entering their password is also something that would almost certainly *still* be impossible even if the apps did support sharing local data.  After all, how is the GMail app going to verify that your app should have permission to read all of its data?  Presumably by prompting for your GMail username and password.  Merely being on the same device definitely doesn't imply complete trust.

Using a SyncAdapter and storing the authentication token as demonstrated in the sample project, you should be able to limit the user to entering their credentials once, but that's about the best you're going to be able to do.

---

**Previously:**

Have you had a look at the SampleSyncAdapter included with the SDK?

[These instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) give a quick overview of how to access the samples.

If you're using Eclipse, it's actually even easier then they suggest there.  To get the sample project:

1. Select `File` > `New` > `Other...`
2. Choose `Android` > `Android Sample Project`
3. Choose whichever target/API Level is applicable to your project (probably the latest)
4. Select the sample project you're interested in, SampleSyncAdapter in this case

The sample project is a great example of how to use SyncAdapters and should be readily adaptable to connect with GMail, Facebook, etc.

Comment: sadly , yes, i have tried it , and i've seen that not only it asks for userName and password (even though i have gmail) , but it also doesn't succeed to login (and i do enter the correct userName and password) and to show me anything that it can do . i also don't think it can do anything with gmail's messages, only contacts (according to the manifest) .

Comment: @androiddeveloper Updated now that I understand your question better.  Note that by default, the SyncAdapter doesn't connect to GMail, but to some purpose-built SyncAdapter service.  You'll have to change it to work with GMail.  That might have been why it wasn't behaving correctly for you.

Comment: are you talking about the sample or about the question of the post? in any case , how come the sample doesn't work without any changes, and how come they don't write down what should be changed? i also don't understand how could it be that i can't find a decent tutorial that works with either gmail or facebook, since they are considered very popular.

Comment: i think that the idea of getting the credential is possible . the first time that you start your device and login to your google account via the google-play app , the gmail app doesn't need to ask you for the userName&password , meaning that it got it from the google-play app . is this correct?